# error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: json, angular, object

in the file 'task.service.ts' I have:

```
getBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/books')
        .map((res) => res.json());
}
```

and I get the  message: "map"does not exist. So, I added at the top:
import 'rxjs' and now I have an error message:
"**

> error TS 2339: Property `JSON` does not exist on type 'Object'

**."

What am I doing wrong? What I forgot about?

Comment: Just like it says, it's not a valid property, meaning res does not have a property named json(). Also, like Saj said, HttpClient already automatically converts the response to JSON so that is not needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With **`HttpClient`**, you don't need map(res => res.json())

```
 getBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.http.get<Book[]>('http://localhost:3000/books');
  }
```

Comment: why would you map res to res?

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta by mistake, made the correction

Comment: Well what Saj said is correct, so what's the error?

Comment: Thx, but after removing I have error:     "error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Book[]>'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Book[]'."

Comment: check the updated answer, you need to cast it. mark if that helped